# What is the different between 2 codes for K-S test

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

What is different between these two codes and when can we use them

I use  K-S test code in R to check normaliity for data that is generated from N(1,6) of size 5

````
#the first code is

x<-rnorm(5,1,6)

ks.test(x,"pnorm",1,6)

#the second code is 
ks.test(x,"pnorm",mean(x),sd(x)) ```
````

Comment: The difference is `1,6` using the theoretical moments of the distribution versus `mean(x),sd(x)` using the empirical moments of the sample.

Comment: The most obvious thing to do\* is *run the code* whence you would see that `mean(x)` is not `1` and `sd(x)` is not `6`. $\:\:$ \*(certainly it would be something you should do before posting, since it would count under the required "search and research" that is mentioned in the help here)